# Regex to get string 'word' from `({#word#})` in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

How do I get string `word` from `({#word#})` using regex in Nodejs?

The regex I'm using right now is: `/\(({#[^)]+#})\)/g`
It gives me string `{#word#}` from `({#word#})`.

How do I get the `word` out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/\(\{#(.*?)#\}\)/g
```

and grab the first capturing group match:

```
/\(\{#(.*?)#\})\)/g.exec("({#test#})")[1] === "test"
```

Capturing groups are expressions between parentheses in a regex that will save the part of the text that matches it. You can have multiple, but in this case we only need one.

The `.*?` is simple but not efficient, if you have a regex for `word` then use that instead.

Learn more about capturing groups:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references

Comment: Regarding the lack of efficiency of `.*?`, you can use `[^#]*` instead. This will disallow values containing `#`, but I'm pretty sure they wouldn't be ok to begin with.